# next-routes custom routes fail on server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js

I'm following an online tutorial that uses next-routes to define custom wildcard routes but I can't get it to work.

#### `server.js`:

```js
const { createServer } = require("http");
const next = require("next");

const app = next({
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
});

const routes = require("./routes");

const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(handler).listen(3000, (e) => {
    if (e) throw e;
    console.log("Ready on localhost:3000");
  });
});
```

#### `routes.js`:

```js
const routes = require("next-routes")();

routes.add("/campaigns/:address(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)", "campaigns/show");

module.exports = routes;


### `campaigns/show.js`:

import React from "react";

class CampaignShow extends React.Component {
    static getInitialProps(props) {
        return {}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h3>Campaign Show</h3>
        )
    }
}

export default CampaignShow
```

When I navigate from the app to `http://localhost:3000/campaigns/0x78E6Fdf23DBA11016c658cc93C4bBb4F63bDAf25` everything works fine and I see the page I expect to see.

However, if I try to open that URL directly, server-side rendering doesn't work and I get a 404 error page.

I get this error in the console:

```
Page does not exist: /campaigns/0x78E6Fdf23DBA11016c658cc93C4bBb4F63bDAf25
Error: Page does not exist: /campaigns/0x78E6Fdf23DBA11016c658cc93C4bBb4F63bDAf25
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/page/campaigns/0x78E6Fdf23DBA11016c658cc93C4bBb4F63bDAf25:3:21
    at register (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/main.js:20505:24)
    at PageLoader.registerPage (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/main.js:20530:9)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/main.js:18414:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/main.js:18410:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/manifest.js:714:31)
    at fn (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/manifest.js:117:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/main.js:13708:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/_next/1543962700127/manifest.js:714:31)

GET http://localhost:3000/campaigns/0x78E6Fdf23DBA11016c658cc93C4bBb4F63bDAf25 404 (Not Found)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code of the getInitialProps method?

Comment: I've just added it to the post. It just returns an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line on top of your `show`

```
import {withRouter} from 'next/router'
```

and update your export to this:

```
export default withRouter(CampaignShow)
```

Comment: Nop, it didn't fix it. Still getting the same error. Even if I change the last line to `export default withRouterASDFASDF(CampaignShow)` it shows the 404 page not found error. Looks like it doesn't even run that line.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps), `getInitialProps` should be placed outside of your React component, like so:

```
import React from "react";

class CampaignShow extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h3>Campaign Show</h3>
        )
    }
}

Page.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  return { }
}

export default CampaignShow
```

Note that `getInitialProps` only does server-side fetching on the initial page load, and client-side fetching on client-side routing.